# I have come across an error with my program. The error is(I think) is changing the source of the image.

Tags: javascript, html

The error is that the image is not changing. The code does not replace the image of the traffic light with the next state. Can anyone help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>Traffic Lights</head>
<body onload = "setInterval(MainSequence(), 2000)">
    <h1>Javascript Traffic Lights</h1>
    <button onclick = "MainSequence()">Click here to change the lights</button>
    <img id = "myImage" src = "RedLight.png" width = "270" height = "400"></img>
    <script>
    var LightStates = newArray("RedLight.png", "RedandAmberLight.png", "GreenLight.png", "AmberLight.png");
    var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
    function MainSequence(){
        if (image.src === (LightStates[0])){
            //changes the source of the image
            image.src = LightStates[1];
            return;
        }
        if (image.src === (LightStates[1])){
            image.src = LightStates[2];
            return;
        }
        if (image.src === (LightStates[2])){
            image.src === LightStates[3];
            return;
        }
        if (image.src === (LightStates[3])){
            image.src = LightStates[0];
            return;
        }
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

declare a new variable

```
var lightIndex =0;
```

and 
in MainSequence function use like this:

```
lightIndex = (lightIndex +1)%LightStates.length;
image.src = LightStates[lightIndex ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you run your entire loop over every time your MainSequence function is called. Your current implementation sees that the current state is 0, then switches to 1, then sees the current state is 1, then switches to 2, etc. until it come back to 0. Then there is an interval of 2000ms. I recommend declaring a new variable:

```
var lightNumber = 0;
```

and then changing your MainSequence to the much simpler:

```
function MainSequence(){
    lightNumber++;
    if (lightNumber > 3){
         lightNumber = 0;
    }
    image.src = lightStates[lightNumber];
}
```